# In web industry, how do you save image? binary or local file?

Tags: php, mysql, image

Say I'm using php+mysql.

I can use:

```
    ob_start();
    readfile($imgurl);
    $img = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
```

to catch the binary string of a picture.
I can save the binary string into mysql as imagedata, and use php to create a image object every time I want to display the image. Or I can use php file system functions to write a local image file using the binary string.

Which way is common in website industry? I assume latter is more popular, cuz you can reduce the traffic connecting your database and for some websites, you can open the original image file with a click on the image. I guess they are saving images as local files. Am I right?
Thx.

Comment: The common is to let webserver do its work - serve the content

Comment: You really need to learn about `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: That seems a little over-complicated. Generally the only thing that is saved in a mysql database is the path to a file that has been uploaded using php. When it comes time to serve the file php grabs the path and displays it in html

Comment: sorry guys, I was using this code to grab images from online source, not from someone's upload

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to save the images in directory and store the path in database. So while accessing you retrieve just the path.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "So while accessing you retrieve just the path."?